# Slow boot after Nvidia driver install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I need some help!

I have just bought an extra SSD exclusive for running Ubuntu (- have Windows on another SSD).
It installs just fine - and boots quick. At first, when I boot up Ubuntu I get some crashes, but nothing serious. BUT after I install Nvidia drivers for my GTX970 card, the boot is SOO slow. From 5-6s to 50+ sec. At least I dont get the crashes after, and when im booted everything runs just fine. 
I have tried different drivers, and reinstalled Ubuntu (both 15.10 and the LTS 4 times) - it always comes down to slow boot after the nvidia drivers. 
After boot in terminal, in 'dmesg', I get some 'error -110' and it looks like some USB problems.

Anyone got any ideas how to fix?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an SD card inserted? Sometimes there can be problems mounting SD cards at boot that hangs things up and causes error 110. It may also be related to a USB device like you suggest, but I've experienced similar behaviour on laptops with touchscreens. It's impossible to provide a specific answer without knowing more details about your machine and the exact error messages you're receiving. Try removing any SD cards and all USB devices and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. 
I dont have any SD card mounted. Its a desktop computer - posted my log further down

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of my dmesg log were it hangs:

[    1.498594] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3499.997 MHz

[    2.500232] Switched to clocksource tsc

[   10.984537] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110

[   11.096617] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd

[   21.239535] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110

[   21.351611] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd

[   26.375040] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[   31.502546] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[   31.718765] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd

[   32.813379] EXT4-fs (sdc2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[   36.742145] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[   41.869666] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110

[   41.973776] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device

[   42.085922] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd

[   42.216096] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b09

[   42.216098] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0

[   42.216099] usb 1-5: Product: Corsair K70R Gaming Keyboard

[   42.216100] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Corsair

[   42.382353] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd

[   42.512522] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0043

[   42.512523] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0

[   42.512524] usb 1-6: Product: Razer DeathAdder Chroma

[   42.512525] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Razer